# Margin auto goes to negative values

Tags: html, css, margin

I have problem with margin: auto - vertical centering 
`#something {
    width: 97%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}`

This work in every modern browser - when the page (viewport) is higher then 300px, its centered vertically, but, when the page(viewport) is lower then 300px stopped it works everywhere except in firefox... In firefox run it good (maybe it is bad functionalitiy, but its logical functionality) in other browsers the top of centered element disappers in the top of viewport.

http://jsfiddle.net/LhHed/2/ Here is god example - when you resize result window, in firefox work it well, in others browsers not. Is posible tu fix it? Or its bad functionality of firefox?

EDIT: live example http://dev8.newlogic.cz

Comment: I'm confused as to what your asking here? Checked in FireFox/chrome and IE and it appears to perform identically in each. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: http://dev8.newlogic.cz/ here is live example... When you resize browser window, top of conteint is on top of browser, but in negative margins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the problem in browsers, when i use `position: relative` to the body element. Now its working in firefox and in other browser too. Live example on http://dev8.newlogic.cz

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, you're wanting the top of the divider to display at the top of the page. This currently isn't happening because you have the position set to `top:0; bottom:0;`, the `top` property is conflicted by the `bottom` property, ultimately positions the divider to the bottom of the page. Simply removing the `bottom` property prevents the top of the element appearing outside of the viewport:

```
#something {
    width: 97%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LhHed/3/).

Comment: definitely not... it is working properly, because top and bottom is set to 0 and margin to auto, so that #something is centered verticaly... see http://dev8.newlogic.cz for live example

Comment: For centring vertically you only need `margin: 0 auto;` you do not need the absolute positioning. Your question makes it difficult to understand what you're actually wanting to happen.

Comment: Yep, my english is bad... i don't need margin: 0 auto; because it is horizontaly centering, or am I mistaken sides?

Comment: Doh sorry, I'm mixing up my verticals and horizontals! Absolute positioning isn't the way to go, however. See: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Comment: `margin: {top/bottom} {left:right};` so `margin: 0 auto` sets top/bottom to `0` and left/right to `auto`.

Comment: ok, once more: http://dev8.newlogic.cz - when you open it in browser, it displayed corectly. The content (photos, logos) are in center of page (top, bottom). But when browser height is lower then height of content it stop working in all browsers except firefox.