# Chrome & Safari Absolute Div Display Issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

For some reason when you go to the homepage of my site:

bluestarnj.com on chrome or safari the top of the page is cut off. This only occurs on laptops with small browser heights. It renders perfectly fine in firefox. Now if I tell it to position itself 300px from the top, it will render correctly in those browsers, but then in firefox it is pushed too far down the page. CSS code for the class is below:

```
.main_content {
width: 1000px;
height: 900px;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 50px; 
left: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
right: 0;
background: linear-gradient(white, grey);
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0.188em;
border-radius: 1.563em;
border-color: red;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: It displays correctly without an issue on desktops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `margin: auto;` from your `.main_content` div.

When the window is smaller than that div it's still centering itself but at the cost of going off the page. Don't worry about vertical centering on smaller screens, and just do that on desktop once the viewport is bigger than that div.

Comment: Thanks dude, yeah I just switched margin to margin-left & right and had no issues. I was thinking it was a margin issue, should've tried it before I wasted people's time asking the question!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the margin of the "main_content" div. I tested on my laptop and on a huge monitor with chrome and this is what I get:

[image: Chrome margin diagram]

As you can see, on a smaller screen the top and bottom margins become negative. I found this question: [Margin auto goes to negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133843/margin-auto-goes-to-negative-values) where someone mentioned a conflict between `top` and `bottom`. This is exactly the case here: you set the top and the bottom as well as the fixed height. For some reason Chrome first sets the top to 50, then tries to adjust the margin (because it's set to auto) so that bottom will be 0. Remove `bottom: 0px` and it works!

EDIT: but it won't be centered vertically anymore.